# How to use inhomogeneous models fitted in the calculation of envelopes in spatstat?

Tags: r, spatstat

This question involves conceptual issues, however, it also involves code. Given a heterogeneous pattern of points, dependent on terrain slope and elevation, for example, obtained from a fit of a poisson model where lambda is equal to a loglinear function of the covariates:

```
fit<- ppm(X~1+elev+grad, data= bei.extra)
```

My question is, when intending to calculate a `g inhom` to test whether these variables can help explain the heterogeneity of the spatial pattern of a false aggregation (virtual aggregation) observed in `g`, how should I proceed with the code? I think it could be like this:

```
g<-envelope(fit, pcfinhom, correction="isotropic", divisor="d", lambda=fit, nsim = 199)
```

The code above runs, but I'd like to know if it's appropriate to put the `fit` model both as the parsing point pattern and also equal to the `lambda`, our since fit is a lambda log, I don't know if it's appropriate to use it without transformation. Or if just like this:

```
g<-envelope(fit, pcfinhom, correction="isotropic", divisor="d", nsim = 199)
```

Since fit is a lambda log, I don't know if it's appropriate to use it without transformation to `ginhom`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inhomogeneous pair correlation function requires an estimate of the intensity of the point process. In the first command this intensity estimate is obtained from a point process model; in the second command the intensity estimate is obtained by kernel smoothing. So the two commands are doing different things.

In the first command

```
envelope(fit, pcfinhom, lambda=fit, .....)
```

the argument `lambda` is passed to `pcfinhom`. For each simulated point pattern `Xsim`, the envelope code calls `pcfinhom(Xsim, lambda=fit, ...)`. According to the help file for `pcfinhom`, the model `fit` will be re-fitted to the pattern `Xsim`, and the intensity of this re-fitted or updated model will be used as the intensity `lambda` for calculation in `pcfinhom`.

In the second command

```
envelope(fit, pcfinhom, ....)
```

the argument `lambda` required by `pcfinhom` is missing. For each simulated pattern `Xsim` the envelope code will call `pcfinhom(Xsim, ....)`. According to the help file for `pcfinhom`, the intensity will be estimated by kernel smoothing of `Xsim` using `density.ppp`. The result in this second case could be changed by adding arguments like `bw` to control the smoothing bandwidth or bandwidth selection rule.

The first command could be regarded as corresponding to a parametric test of goodness-of-fit, while the second command could be regarded as a nonparametric or semiparametric test of goodness-of-fit, of the same fitted model.

However in your question you say

> My question is, when intending to calculate a g inhom to test whether these variables can help explain the heterogeneity of the spatial pattern of a false aggregation (virtual aggregation) observed in `g`

A simulation envelope is not really the best way to assess such a question. The simulation envelopes correspond to an overall test of goodness-of-fit, and do not provide specific information about variables in the model (such as, which are the variables whose omission causes a lack of fit).

For this it might be better to use diagnostics such as the residual K function `Kres`, or the analysis of deviance (likelihood ratio test) `anova.ppm`. Example:

```
fit0 <- ppm(bei ~ 1, data=bei)
fit1 <- ppm(bei ~ elev + grad, data=bei)
anova(fit0, fit1, test="Chi")
```

Comment: Thanks, Professor. In this context , a first command is similar a un partial residuals (`parres`), correct? with a difference that `parres` analyse one covariate for turn.